# Capturing RTP packets to file for later processing using WebRTC native API

Tags: c++, webrtc

From [this WebRTC Code and API page](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/webrtc-internals/voertp_rtcp#TOC-StartRTPDump):

> StartRTPDump
>
> This function enables capturing of RTP packets to a binary file on  a
>   specific channel and for a given direction.  The file can later be
>   replayed using e.g. RTP Tools’ rtpplay since  the binary file format
>   is compatible with the rtpdump format.

NOTE: It is recommended that you use this API **for debugging purposes only** since the created files can become very large.

What is a recommended way to save RTP packets into a file for later processing?